# Set the maximum number of row to be added

Tags: odoo-12

we are working on a project and this project have the below requirements:

A. project scope is Employee Attendance at Each company Branch
B. each branch has a different maximum number of Employees
C. we want in the attendance screen, to be only limited by the Max. number of the Employees in this Branch,so no one can record an attendance for a number of the employees that exceed the maximum number already registered
based on the below Users Stories

**Story 1**: *as a supervisor*, i want to set the max number on employees for each branch, so no more entries could be accepted. i.e:*Branch 1 = 5, Branch 2 = 8,  Branch 3 = 3*

**Story 2:** as *an HR represented in the Branch*, i must see just the number of row for each branch
or, the attendance screen don't accept more than the max number
so, there is no error to record unrelated employee number

Comment: Did you try to use  [api.constraints](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/api.py#L101)?

Comment: thank you, i will try it